# How to autorun a script as root just after the user's encrypted home directory has become mounted on headless server?

Tags: scripts, upstart, ecryptfs

There is a problem with `ecryptfs` that it heavily limits the maximal filename length.

To walkaround it I link most home subfolders to the external encrypted partition. The partition gets mounted just after a successful login with the key file that is present on the freshly-mounted encrypted `$HOME`.

The problem is, that mounting external partitions needs `root` rights, and execution just after a successful login.

For GUI systems, one can achieve it by adding a file into `/etc/init` with the following contents:

```
description "runs mounter as superuser for a user on logon as root"

start on desktop-session-start

exec /usr/local/sbin/mounter.sh
```

where `mounter.sh` is the actual mounting script, which can be something like the following:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /home/myname/key.bin /dev/disk/by-uuid/ce2cd926-133f-4e20-86f8-45bc4844271c my-docs
mount -t btrfs -o compress,rw,noacl,noatime,autodefrag  /dev/mapper/my-docs /home/myname/docs
chown myname:myname /home/myname/docs
chmod 0775 /home/myname/docs
sync
```

Now, how to make it run on **headless** server machines? There is no `desktop-session-start` event, but still, upon first successful login the system somehow manages to open `ecryptfs` and then to close it, when the last user logs off.

Is there any upstart event that gets triggered when an encrypted home is mounted?